# gradle unable to establish connection behind proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy, react-native

I am trying to run the react native examples for androind on windows. My system is setup behind a corporate proxy. i am unable to get gradle to work though.
Following proxy settings are defined in the global gradle.properties.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<proxy.url>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<proxy.url>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

I tried running the build from android studio(2.0), same story. My network proxy is properly configured there, i checked, i can access the internet from it.
i changed my build tools to point to the gradle distribution that comes with it, that didn't change anything either. 
i keep getting an error saying

```
"Unknown host <my.proxy.url>. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in gradle"
```

I also checked, i can download the poms it requires from my browser. it seems as if gradle is unable to work from behind a proxy, at all.
can anyone help?